# Best regular expression for matching URI in http header

Tags: php, regex

I have http header string

```
GET /phpmyadmin/sql.php?db=monitor&table=boundries&token=08b1cd52b3bc0068ea470988e292f54d&pos=0 HTTP/1.1
Host: mylocalwebhost.net
```

The above is a sample string which I will recieve through a file. In each string I need to check for validity for the first line.

The 'GET' portion can be any of `GET` `PUT` `POST` `DELETE`.

How can I match the first line using a regular expression. Please some one provide me with a valid regex that I can use with php `preg_match()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Regex

```
/^(?:GET|PUT|POST|DELETE) (.*?) \S+$/m
```

### Code

```
<?php
$re = '/^(?:GET|PUT|POST|DELETE) (.*?) \S+$/m'; 
$str = 'GET /phpmyadmin/sql.php?db=monitor&table=boundries&token=08b1cd52b3bc0068ea470988e292f54d&pos=0 HTTP/1.1
        Host: mylocalwebhost.net'; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

Comment: what is the part `?:` in the above regex?

Comment: It makes the group "Non-capturing", so there is no backreference for that group. The middle `(.*?)` is backreferenced as `1`.

Comment: what is the last `/m` means?

Comment: That's a flag for the regex engine to treat the match as `Multiline` which means that `^` and `$` match at the start and end of a line respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
$string = '//phpmyadmin/sql.php?db=monitor&table=boundries&token=08b1cd52b3bc0068ea470988e292f54d&pos=0';

$parts = explode("&", $string);
$parts = array_map("trim", $parts);
foreach($parts as $current)
{
    list($key, $value) = explode("=", $current);
    $data[$key] = $value;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';
```

The result is:

```
Array
(
    [//phpmyadmin/sql.php?db] => monitor
    [table] => boundries
    [token] => 08b1cd52b3bc0068ea470988e292f54d
    [pos] => 0
)
```

Comment: I understand to try to validate part of the url, take as reference the "token" of this  string that is extracted and validated. I apologize if the answer is not the appropriate @fSazy.

`$data['token'];`

Comment: actually the above answer I chosen is the right one.